# How to secure edit form route?

Tags: reactjs

I have this route in my React app:

```
<Route path="/solution/:id/edit" element={user ? <SolutionEditForm /> : <Navigate to="/" />}/>
```

I would like to know how to secure this route, right now if a user is logged in they can access this route, but they can also access someone's solution edit route as well if they are logged in. This route should be accessible only by those who submitted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Private Route`

// Private Route file

```
import { Navigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ user, children }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  // check for user first
  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  // logic to check if `solution` id matches with user id
  // and if not then navigate to "/"

  return children;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Now wrap your route with the above Private Route

```
<Route path="/solution/:id/edit" element={<PrivateRoute user={user}><SolutionEditForm /></PrivateRoute>}/>
```